# JMeter: Creating Proper UPDATE Calls for API CRUD Testing

Tags: api, jmeter

I'm performing API testing of basic CRUD functionality. For a record creation, I need to take the response, modify a field, and save the full thing off as a file so i can be recalled for an Update.

Here is what occurs for the creation.

CREATE POST Body

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "apiTest: Code Rate ${__Random(1,10000000)}",
    "deletable": false,
    "codePeriods": null
}
```

CREATE RESPONSE Body

```
{
  "name": "apiTest: Code Rate 869531",
  "id": 1257745140,
  "deletable": true,
  "codePeriods": null,
  "lastChangedDateTime": "03/01/2016 10:13:09",
  "lastChangedTime": 36789410,
  "createdUser": {
    "id": 1003941890,
    "userName": "N9SFBulkUser"
  },
  "lastChangedDate": 736024,
  "lastChangedUser": {
    "id": 1003941890,
    "userName": "N9SFBulkUser"
  },
  "createdDateTime": "03/01/2016 10:13:09"
}
```

*I need to change the "name" field in order to perform an UPDATE on the record*.

As of now, I have:

- a *RegEx* to extract the name field value and save it. (newCodeRate)
- a *Save Response to a file* to save off the entire response. (newCodeRateFile)
- another *HTTP Request* to **update** the record where:

  Body Data = `${__fileToString(${__eval(${newCodeRateFile})},,)}`

As you can see, right now it's just taking the previous response, saving it to a file and then being re-sent. This is not a proper UPDATE as the database sees nothing has changed and just ignores it. Sure, I get a 200 OK response, but it's misleading as nothing was updated. You can tell this because the Creation and Update date/times still match.

I was thinking maybe I need a BSF PostProcessor where (using Javascript):

```
var data = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
var object = JSON.parse(data);
vars.put("name", object.name);
```

But not being a developer by trade, I'm not sure how what to do with this and how to save the new name value into the saved recallable file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think you have `JSON` in BSF JavaScript, it is not part of [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino)
2. I don't think you need to store response into a file and read it, you can do it in memory.

So:

1. Change your [__Random](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function to store generated value into a JMeter Variable like:

   ```
   ${__Random(1,10000000,randomNumber)}
   ```
2. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of CREATE request and configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `body`
   - Regular Expression: `(?s)(^.*)`
   - Template: `$1$`
3. Add [__Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function as UPDATE request body, it should look like:

   ```
   ${__BeanShell(return vars.get("body").replaceAll(vars.get("randomNumber")\,"${__Random(1,10000000)}");,)}
   ```

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more comprehensive information on JMeter functions.

Comment: Dimitri, Thank you very much. I would not have thought of using a Beanshell function in my request body. Using your 3 steps worked perfectly. I'm now trying to familiarize myself with the RegEx syntax and reviewing your blog post for a better understanding, but, wow, thank you very much for the assist!